# Ipython shell won't start

Tags: emacs, ipython

I have ipython.el and python-mode.el installed in my path, and I have the following added to my init.el:

```
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python editing mode." t)
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.py$" . python-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq interpreter-mode-alist (cons '("python" . python-mode) interpreter-mode-alist))
(setq ipython-command "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/ipython")
(require 'ipython)
```

But python-mode insists on launching the python interpreter instead of ipython. Changing py-python-command doesn't help either.

How do I get Ipython to be the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) 
Same question when I want to using ipython in emacs.

Infact, new python-mode provide another method to invoke ipython. 
You just simply call that method will solve this. (bind function to keys you need)
You can using command:

```
M-x ipython
```

to using ipython

execute code in ipython by calling:

```
M-x py-execute-buffer-ipython
```

But, honestly, using ipython in emacs is slower and using

```
py-execute-buffer
```

in python-mode can handle almost all questions(easy to change code, move cursor or any requirements).